# C#: transcribe WAV file to text (speech-to-text) with System.Speech namespaces

Tags: c#, namespaces, speech-to-text

How do you use the .NET speech namespace classes to convert audio in a [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) file to textual form which I can display on the screen or save to file?

I am looking for some tutorial samples.

### UPDATE

Found a code sample [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/9c6eff5f-94a7-429b-b277-fee7c730bb1a/). But when I tried it it gives incorrect results. Below is the vb code sample I've adopted. (Actually I don't mind the lang as long as its either vb/c#...). It is not giving me proper results. I assume if we put the right grammar - i.e. the words we expect in the recording - we should get the textual output of that. First I've tried with sample words that are in the call. It sometimes printed only that (one) word and nothing else. Then I tried words which we totally do not expect in the recording...Unfortunately it printed out that too... :(

```
Imports System
Imports System.Speech.Recognition

Public Class Form1

    Dim WithEvents sre As SpeechRecognitionEngine

    Private Sub btnLiterate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLiterate.Click
        If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then Exit Sub
        sre.SetInputToWaveFile(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim r As RecognitionResult
        r = sre.Recognize()
        If r Is Nothing Then
            TextBox2.Text = "Could not fetch result"
            Return
        End If
        TextBox2.Text = r.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
        Dim dr As DialogResult
        dr = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If dr = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            If Not OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Contains("wav") Then
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect file")
            Else
                TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        sre = New SpeechRecognitionEngine()

    End Sub

    Private Sub sre_LoadGrammarCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.LoadGrammarCompletedEventArgs) Handles sre.LoadGrammarCompleted

    End Sub

    Private Sub sre_SpeechHypothesized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs) Handles sre.SpeechHypothesized
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(e.Result.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub sre_SpeechRecognitionRejected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs) Handles sre.SpeechRecognitionRejected
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Rejected: " & e.Result.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub sre_SpeechRecognized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognizedEventArgs) Handles sre.SpeechRecognized
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(e.Result.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim words As String() = New String() {"triskaidekaphobia"}
        Dim c As New Choices(words)
        Dim grmb As New GrammarBuilder(c)
        Dim grm As Grammar = New Grammar(grmb)
        sre.LoadGrammar(grm)
    End Sub

End Class
```

### UPDATE(after Nov 28th)

Found a way to load a default grammar. It goes something like this:

```
sre.LoadGrammar(New DictationGrammar)
```

There are still problems here. The recognition is not exact. The output is rubbish. For a 6min file it gives probably 5-6 words of text totally irrelevant to the voice file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The classes in System.Speech are for text to speech (primarily an acessibility feature).

You are looking for voice recognition. There is the [System.Speech.Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx) namespace available since .Net 3.0. It uses the Windows Desktop Speech engine. This might get you started, but I guess there are better engines out there.

Voice recognition is very complicated and hard to do right, there are also some commercial products available.

Comment: will this require actually "playing" the voice file?

Comment: Maybe that and then rooting the audio output to the mic input like some cd rippers do. Otherwise try checking out how SpeechRecognizer.EmulateRecognize works with reflector.

Comment: Maybe check that out also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.audioformat.speechaudioformatinfo_members.aspx

sorry, Im no expert for that. Hope it helps you.

Comment: The EmulateRecognize won't help - it's meant to bypass the recognition by giving the recognized output.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but there is better information available in later questions and answers. For example see [What is the best option for transcribing speech-to-text in a asp.net web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730318/what-is-the-best-option-for-transcribing-speech-to-text-in-a-asp-net-web-app/4737003#4737003)

Instead of calling SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice() you can call SetInputToWaveFile() to read from an audio file.

The desktop recognition engine that comes in Windows Vista and Windows 7 includes a dictation grammar as shown in the referenced answer.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need Natural Language toolkit.  In python I have used [NTLK](http://www.nltk.org/) http://www.nltk.org/

[In .Net I have just found Antelope 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762040/natural-language-toolkit-equivalent-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762040/natural-language-toolkit-equivalent-in-c)

see the article as well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`SpeechRecognitionEngine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx). To use a wave file, call [`SetInputToWaveFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtowavefile.aspx). I wish I could help you more, but I'm no expert.

Oh, and if your word is really `triskaidekaphobia`, I don't think even a human speech recognition engine would recognize that...