# Taking input from MIC and converting into text

Tags: c#

I'am making a windows form DICTIONARY application in iam taking input from user as a audio than converting it into a text word...
Then application show the meaning of the word(given in audio form)

i want a code which would help me in converting the audio file in text file

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: transcribe WAV file to text (speech-to-text) with System.Speech namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768679/c-transcribe-wav-file-to-text-speech-to-text-with-system-speech-namespaces)

Answer (score 0):

This could help you:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/ssrinivas/speeechrecognitionusingcsharp11222005054918am/speeechrecognitionusingcsharp.aspx

Next time, google things up :S

Comment: You seem to be new here, because [Google](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions) [is not](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) [an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) nor helpful in the most cases.

Comment: yup you right right sometime google is able to gave you the prefect solution that you are expecting.....